# Positioning controls - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am in the process of teaching myself WPF and have an issue that is confusing me. In the XAML below when  I open the app the label and image are in the top left part of the window, but when I maximize the window they shift towards the middle. What am I missing that will make the controls keep their relative position?

```xml
<Window x:Class="WafLuckyDog.Presentation.Views.ShellWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"  
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WafLuckyDog.Applications.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Title="{Binding Title}" Icon="{StaticResource ApplicationIcon}" Width="994.273" Height="840"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:ShellViewModel}">

    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource Background}"></ImageBrush>
    </Window.Background>
    <DockPanel Margin="0,0,-539,0">

    <Grid>
        <Image  Name="Logo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,669" Width="129" 
                Source="{StaticResource Logo}" />
        <Label Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,145,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="AntiqueWhite"/>
    </Grid>
   </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Margin="0,10,0,669" left margin is 669px.
When you enlarge your window, you'll see the margin more clearly

Comment: @DieterB 669 is the botton margin, not in pixels, but in device-independent units.

Comment: @DieterB the last is the bottom margin. Left, Up, Right, Down

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a `DockPanel` that has no close tag and is doing nothing, it will give a compile error, so remove it. Also, remove the bottom margin and add a `Height` and `VerticalAlignment` properties. The `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` ensures a top right corner anchor.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WafLuckyDog.Presentation.Views.ShellWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"  
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WafLuckyDog.Applications.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Title="{Binding Title}" Icon="{StaticResource ApplicationIcon}" Width="994.273" Height="840"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:ShellViewModel}">

    <Window.Background>
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource Background}"></ImageBrush>
    </Window.Background>

    <Grid>
      <Image  Name="Logo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129" Height="129" 
          Source="{StaticResource Logo}" />
      <Label Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,145,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="AntiqueWhite"/>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: That worked.  After years of winforms and ASP.net and more than my share of console apps.,this is going to be an exciting learning curve